# Use COUNT and add the the value of two columns together

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have this table which contains the values of a vote:

```
+-------+-------+
| Vote1 | Vote2 |
+-------+-------+
| Mr. X | Mr. Y |
| Mr. X | Mr. Z |
| Mr. Y | Mr. X |
| Mr. Z | Mr. X |
+-------+-------+
```

Now I need the total occurrence of every person mentioned in the table, like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| Person | Votes |
+--------+-------+
| Mr. X  |     4 |
| Mr. Y  |     2 |
| Mr. Z  |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```

For now I have to calculate the sum by hand by making COUNT queries for each of the two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `union all` operator to serialize the two columns:

```
SELECT   person, COUNT(*) AS votes
FROM     (SELECT vote1 AS person
          FROM   mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT vote2 AS person
          FROM   mytable) t
GROUP BY person
```

Answer (score 2):

For higher performance, Use this query:

`SELECT Vote1 Person,
(Count(Vote1) + Count(Vote2))Votes 
FROM mytable GROUP BY Vote1`

or

`SELECT Vote2 Person,
(Count(Vote1) + Count(Vote2))Votes 
FROM mytable GROUP BY Vote2`

As much as possible refrain from using `UNION or UNION ALL`.